# Unable to upload any file exceeding the size of 250 MB in struts 1.1

Tags: java, struts-1, struts-config

I have encountered an unusual behavior with respect to file upload capability in Struts 1.1 application.

I have configured the max upload file size limit using the  tag in struts configuration file as follows.

Struts uses common fileupload library to handle file uploading functionality by default and if the file being uploaded exceeds the max file size, it sets a request-scopedattribute in the type of Boolean, under the name of the constant value : MultipartRequestHandler.ATTRIBUTE_MAX_LENGTH_EXCEEDED.

But I experienced an unusual behavior with large file upload. When uploading a larger file which is 300MB in size.

Is there any solution for that?

Am I missing something?

I'm using Struts 1.1 and common file upload 1.2 combination.

Also, I re-tested the same functionality with common file uploads 1.3, but the behavior is same.

Does anyone have any idea on solving this?

Comment: You say "experienced an unusual behavior". What exactly happens?

Comment: If I try to upload a file with size less than 250 MB, it gets uploaded to the server. However, if the size exceeds 250 MB, it fails..

Comment: What you mean by "fail"? What error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. I am suspecting the form is not getting submitted.

Comment: Any errors in server logs?

Comment: No, I can't find any error in server logs. While I was googling, I read Struts (by default) supports 250 MB of file to get uploaded. So, I tried to change the value of maxFileSize in struts.config <controller maxFileSize="300M" />. However, it made no difference. Can't find any error too..